# Checking Content of Arguement: Error: [: missing `]' & command not found

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement

I am trying to write a script that takes a argument, and depending on the user provided argument, initializes a variable containing a file path; however, I am running into issues as it looks like something is wrong with my if else statement and my string isnt being read as a string but as a command name....

```
#!/bin/bash
PROJ_DIR='./'

if [ $1 == "All" | $1 == "all" | $1 == "ALL" ]
then
        OUT_FILEPATH_1=$PROJ_DIR/All/1
        OUT_FILEPATH_2=$PROJ_DIR/All/2
elif [ $1 == "Euro" || $1 == "euro" || $1 == "EURO" ]
then
        OUT_FILEPATH_1=$PROJ_DIR/Euro/1
        OUT_FILEPATH_2=$PROJ_DIR/Euro/2
else
        echo "Incorrect Choice"
        exit 1
fi

echo $OUT_FILEPATH_1
echo $OUT_FILEPATH_2
```

Then I run: `./testingifelse.sh "euro"`

and I receive 6 error messages AND the `else` command runs:

```
./testingifelse.sh: line 3: [: missing `]'
./testingifelse.sh: line 3: all: command not found
./testingifelse.sh: line 3: ALL: command not found
./testingifelse.sh: line 7: [: missing `]'
./testingifelse.sh: line 7: euro: command not found
./testingifelse.sh: line 7: euro: command not found
Incorrect Choice
```

Comment: The operator `|` denotes a _pipe_, which allows you to fedd the stdout of one process into the stdin of another process. In your code, so try to pipe the output of `[ $1 == "All"` into the input of `$1 == "all"`.  This explains the error messages you got.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The "or" condition in bash is `||` not `|` (the latter is a pipe).
2. Your "or" condition is incorrectly formatted within your if statement. Each condition within the `if` must be contained within `[ ... ]` and you can separate multiple conditions like `[ ... ] || [ ... ]`.
3. You should quote your variables within these conditions when they are referenced. This is for safety (in case you call the program without arguments in this case).

Try this instead:

```
#!/bin/bash
PROJ_DIR='./'

if [ "$1" = "All" ] || [ "$1" = "all" ] || [ "$1" = "ALL" ]
then
        OUT_FILEPATH_1=$PROJ_DIR/All/1
        OUT_FILEPATH_2=$PROJ_DIR/All/2
elif [ "$1" = "Euro" ] || [ "$1" = "euro" ] || [ "$1" = "EURO" ]
then
        OUT_FILEPATH_1=$PROJ_DIR/Euro/1
        OUT_FILEPATH_2=$PROJ_DIR/Euro/2
else
        echo "Incorrect Choice"
        exit 1
fi

echo $OUT_FILEPATH_1
echo $OUT_FILEPATH_2
```

Comment: ok, this is a great alternative solution. thanks so much.

Comment: `==` should be `=` with `[` -- the POSIX standard doesn't document `==` at all, but mandates `=` to work as a string comparison operator; see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html

Answer (score 0):

When comparing strings, you must use `[[ a == b ]]` in the if else statement.
Also, the OR statement is not `|` , instead it is `||`. Also the spaces are important.

The correct answer is:

```
#!/bin/bash
PROJ_DIR='./'

if [[ $1 == "All" || $1 == "all" || $1 == "ALL" ]]
then
        OUT_FILEPATH_1=$PROJ_DIR/All/1
        OUT_FILEPATH_2=$PROJ_DIR/All/2
elif [[ $1 == "Euro" || $1 == "euro" || $1 == "EURO" ]]
then
        OUT_FILEPATH_1=$PROJ_DIR/Euro/1
        OUT_FILEPATH_2=$PROJ_DIR/Euro/2
else
        echo "Incorrect Choice"
        exit 1
fi

echo $OUT_FILEPATH_1
echo $OUT_FILEPATH_2
```

Comment: I dont have a reference for the double bracket thing tho...... maybe someone could link... i found this: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031

but it is pretty non-sense jargon to an amateur...

Comment: What part of BashFAQ #31 _specifically_ do you have a question about, and what is that specific question?

Comment: BTW, this would be better written with a `case` statement. For that matter, you can do case-insensitive matches. so you can just check against `all` and `euro` and have `ALL` and `EURO` be covered.

Comment: `shopt -s nocasematch; case $1 in all) dir=All;; euro) dir=Euro; *) echo "Incorrect Choice" >&2; exit 1;; esac; OUT_FILEPATH_1=$PROJ_DIR/$dir/1; OUT_FILEPATH_2=$PROJ_DIR/$dir/2`

Comment: BTW, note that it's bad form to use all-uppercase names for your own variables -- that's the namespace for variables that have meaning to the shell itself, whereas variables with at least one lower-case character in their names are guaranteed not to have unintended side effects on behavior of POSIX-defined tools.

Comment: (For a concrete example of why that guideline exists, think about how `for PATH in /dir/*/; do ...` breaks your shell's ability to run external executables, whereas `for path in /dir/*/; do ...` works fine; the standard-document specification is in https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html -- read it keeping in mind that environment variables and regular shell variables share a single namespace, as setting a shell variable overwrites any like-named environment variable).

Comment: Thanks for all the pointers, makes sense. I guess what I could gather from BashFAQ #31 is that [ ] and [[ ]] are from different programing languages and [[ ]] is more updated?

Comment: `[` is a POSIX-standardized command (meaning that its arguments are parsed according to the same set of rules as any other command, so `|` is still a pipe character, `||` separates it from a new/different command, etc). By contrast, `[[` is nonstandard _syntax_ first introduced by ksh and now supported by several other shells, bash among them. Being syntax lets `[[` do things that `[` can't, like recognizing glob patterns and regular expressions without subjecting them to regular quoting rules; and suppressing parsing steps that don't make sense in the context.

Comment: That's not to disagree, really. `[` is indeed older, and it has the advantage of being useful if you're writing a script that needs to be executable by shells that don't support ksh extensions; `[[` is newer, and adds more features, but it's not available everywhere.

Comment: oh no, that is helpful and makes sense. I have 0 computer science background, I have a great deal to learn. I believe the way you explained it was super helpful and makes/made learning more also easier.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234346/discussion-between-sky-scraper-and-charles-duffy).